# Force word wrap if elements after content needs to be wrapped

Tags: css, word-wrap

I've found a couple questions that sort of address this issue, but not really what I need. I have some text,

`once-weekly dosing regimen` for instance. On this element, there's an after css rule, as such:

```
font-family: FontAwesome;
content: " \f105";
color: #00467f;
```

I have these elements in a typical grid, and when you resize window smaller, eventually the `:after` content (the arrow) will go to next line, which is fine. However, I'm trying to make it so the last word will also wrap with the after content. I've tried a couple answers I found to similar questions with no prevail, which include: setting `display: inline-block` to both elements, I messed with the `white-space` and `word-wrap` properties with no luck and I've tried setting a width to the `:after` rule as well with no prevail. What I did find to sort of work is setting the `white-space: nowrap` rule on the element itself, which stops the `:after` content from wrapping, however isn't exactly what I want.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmm. I mean, the issue is I can't just make the last word a separate element, because it doesn't always need to be broke. Just on certain widths, which I was hoping css could solve. But you're saying that's not possible?

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah, I guess it wouldn't be the end of the world do just make the last word it's own element, and it seems like the only way to achieve. Sorry for not having demo, I usually do. If you want to make it an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to wrap that last word in a separate element (probably with the pseudo-element on that). You can't *force* a break in raw text on overflow.

Something like:

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

span::after {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: " \f105";
  color: #00467f;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
  padding: .25rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div>
  once-weekly dosing <span>regimen</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that what u are looking for?
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hfgq68a7/1/)

```
div {
    width: 40px;
    background: yellow;
}
.breaked {
    word-break: break-word
}
.text:after {
    content: 'After';
    color: blue;
}
```

Just simply change width, and it will wrap as one word.

EDIT: updated jsfiddle and SCSS to CSS

Comment: I think you made a mistake formatting your link, intrigued to see though!

Comment: You're using SCSS here.

Comment: adding a word-break: break-word; to .text will wrap a word and after as one word

Comment: Yes I am. If this is what u want i can introduce pure css version

Comment: That would be ideal, if you can.

Comment: Actually you were sort of right with the `word-break` thing. I was trying `word-wrap` before. You learn something new everyday. When I use the `word-break` it's much better, but not quite 100%. I still see the after content wrapping and not the word in some cases.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, really good solution. I would mark it as the answer, however it's pretty similar to the answer already marked. I do really appreciate you taking the time and I have upvoted this answer so you got some rep from it :D. Thanks again man.

Comment: U're welcome :) It depends what are u really want. I found @Paulie_D solution good too - but it involves changing the HTML.

Comment: So does yours though, right? You're using a span for the last word, which is what Paulie was suggesting. Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: No I'm not. see a fiddle. There is no span for last word

Comment: I was wrong. Sorry about that. There is a slight issue with your solution though, that's not necessarily your fault but doesn't quite do what I need it to. The issue is that in your example you're using `After` and for whatever reason that works, but a single character like `>` doesn't quite wrap the same way. Also, I don't have a width set on the parent, again not your fault, I didn't post my html so that's my fault. Here's an updated fiddle that shows you what I'm talking about. https://jsfiddle.net/hfgq68a7/2/